# I want to match data from my database to googlelocation dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[This is my website](http://dev.appcotech.com/pwrdup/static/become-postie.php) UnderConstruction please go to upper link and click on SIGNUP TO DRIVE (Blue cruve Button) there will be a tab open type `london` (Not From Drop Down) only just type `london` and hit enter page will redirect to

dev.appcotech.com/pwrdup/static/become-postie-vehicle.php

page (This mean post keyword matched 100% with database) than come back to previous page and again type `london` now this time from Dropdown menu
you will find `London, United Kingdom`,and hit enter. They are same city but my database have only keyword `london`.so page will redirect to

dev.appcotech.com/pwrdup/static/city-unavailables.php

This mean result not matched 100%

I want to match only city `London, United Kingdom` to my database Keyword `london`.
I only have letters `london` in my database here is my code.

```
require_once "connection/connection.php";
if($_POST)
{ 
   $a  = $_POST['address'] ;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_city WHERE city_name LIKE '%$a%'"; 
   $res  = mysql_query($sql);   
   $result = mysql_fetch_array($res); 

   if($result >=1){
       header("location:become-postie-vehicle.php");
       die();   
   }else{
       header("location:city-unavailables.php");
       die();
   }
```

where `$a  = $_POST['address'] ;` is input field name (Where it is use for search) so please let me know how can I match the city from my database?my database is given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_city` (
`id` int(100) NOT NULL,
 `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


  INSERT INTO `tbl_city` (`id`, `city_name`) VALUES
  (1, 'london');
```

Now please help me to find out solution. Remember i have used `REGEXP` `MATCH() ... AGAINST` in `$sql` already.it is most challenging ever.
**Anyone have Solution???**

Comment: you mean one match will be available london or United Kingdom at a time

Comment: yes  i want at least one key word like london

Comment: exact match you can use where condition know

Comment: i already use where, would you like to give some example? About where condition know

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_city WHERE city_name = '".$a"'";

Comment: i changed my sql to your sql but it is not working bro...

Comment: echo the sql query  and copy the query and run on the phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

i have got answer from [Daniweb.com](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/497100/i-want-to-match-data-from-my-database-to-googlelocation-dropdown#update-tags)

If you're always going to have the same format of the city with a comma followed by something, you could just write the query with a substring_index to split on the comma. If it isn't always going to be that way, then of course you wouldn't be able to do that.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_city WHERE city_name LIKE SUBSTRING_INDEX('London, United Kingdom', ',', 1);
```

This splits the string on the first comma, and uses the value of 'London' in the search.

OR

You could split the string in PHP prior to running the query.